# Find the angle between the vectors a and b given a condition

Tags: vectors

Given that $(2\vec {a}-\vec{b})\perp(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$ and $(\vec{a}-2\vec{b})\perp(2\vec{a}+{b})$ find the angle between vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

I tried using the fact that

$(2\vec {a}-\vec{b})(\vec{a}+\vec{b})$ = $2\vec{a^2}+\vec{a}\vec{b}-\vec{b^2} = 0$

$(\vec{a}-2\vec{b})(2\vec{a}+{b})$= $2\vec{a^2}-3\vec{a}\vec{b}-2\vec{b^2} = 0$

I tried solving some type of system of these both but that didn't get me far. Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 3):

From the given equations I get $$\vec{a}\vec{b}  = -{2\over 5}a^2 = -{1\over 4}b^2<0$$ so $$(\vec{a}\vec{b})^2  = {1\over 10}a^2b^2$$ so $$\cos \phi = - \sqrt{1\over 10}$$